# Debugger in visual studio waits in 9 seconds before starting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

If I create a .NET console project from scratch (File → New → Project → C# → windows → Console → Console App (.NET Framework) and I debug the following program

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

using <kbd>F5</kbd>

...I will get an empty console window in 9 seconds before the program is running (and the text "test" is echoed).

The delay is the same every time.

Can I change any settings to get rid of the delay? What is Visual Studio doing in 9 seconds?

If I run the program without debugging (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd>), I do not have the delay, but I really need to debug sometimes.

## Edit

I followed the recommendation to upgrade to 17.0.4 and the delay was gone!

Comment: Isn't Visual Studio just compiling during that time? Or is it depending on other running programs?

Comment: When I run instead of debug, there is also compilation involved, but in 0 time?

Comment: I've seen this happening as well, but for me, it only (sometimes) happens the very first time I start debugging. After that, it works as expected. It appears there's a problem launching a process in debug mode, either in Visual Studio or even in the OS kernel.

Comment: Take a backup first, `Tools>Export Settings`, then try turning off different debugging features in `Tools>Options>Debugging` to see if any of them may be causing slowdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have concluded that the delay is introducted in vs2022, so I have to use vs2019 until the problem is fixed!

(Unchecking Options → Debugging → General checkboxes made no difference for me).

The current vs2022 version is 17.0.2.

Comment: I'm using 17.0.4 and do not have this issue, you may upgrade it as the 2022 version has a large performance improvement than VS 2019

Comment: That was the cure! I did the same, updated to 17.0.4 and the delay is gone!